# Confusion with mapping arrays of objects JS / Next / React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Edit: re-wrote question to make it cleaner:
I have data like this,

```
[
  { winrate: '56.67' },
  [
    {
      bout: "Bout 5: Europe's  Qualifiers",
      wins: '2',
      role: 'Alternate'
    },
    {
      pokemon: 'Quagsire',
      sprite: 'https://thesilphroad.com/img/pokemon/icons/96x96/195.png'
    },
    {
      pokemon: 'Venusaur',
      sprite: 'https://thesilphroad.com/img/pokemon/icons/96x96/3.png'
    },
    {
      pokemon: 'Beedrill',
      sprite: 'https://thesilphroad.com/img/pokemon/icons/96x96/15.png'
    },
    {
      pokemon: 'Mawile',
      sprite: 'https://thesilphroad.com/img/pokemon/icons/96x96/303.png'
    },
    {
      pokemon: 'Escavalier',
      sprite: 'https://thesilphroad.com/img/pokemon/icons/96x96/589.png'
    },
    {
      pokemon: 'Mandibuzz',
      sprite: 'https://thesilphroad.com/img/pokemon/icons/96x96/630.png'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      bout: "Bout 4: Europe's  Qualifiers",
      wins: '1',
      role: 'Alternate'
    },
    {
      pokemon: 'Quagsire',
      sprite: 'https://thesilphroad.com/img/pokemon/icons/96x96/195.png'
    },
    {
      pokemon: 'Ninetales_alolan',
      sprite: 'https://thesilphroad.com/img/pokemon/icons/96x96/ninetales-alola.png'
    },
    {
      pokemon: 'Beedrill',
      sprite: 'https://thesilphroad.com/img/pokemon/icons/96x96/15.png'
    },
    {
      pokemon: 'Sealeo',
      sprite: 'https://thesilphroad.com/img/pokemon/icons/96x96/364.png'
    },
    {
      pokemon: 'Jellicent',
      sprite: 'https://thesilphroad.com/img/pokemon/icons/96x96/593.png'
    },
    {
      pokemon: 'Venusaur',
      sprite: 'https://thesilphroad.com/img/pokemon/icons/96x96/3.png'
    }
  ], ...etc it goes on for a while.
```

I'm trying to map it in a react component like this:

```
const Teams = ({ teams }) => {
  let pokemap = teams.map((team, index) => (
    <React.Fragment key={index}>
      <br />
      <div class="container">
        {team.map((pokemon) => (
          <React.Fragment key={pokemon.pokemon}>
            <br /> <div class="bout">{pokemon.bout}</div>
            <div class="child">
              <img src={pokemon.sprite} />
              <p>{pokemon.pokemon}</p>
            </div>
          </React.Fragment>
        ))}
      </div>
      <br />
    </React.Fragment>
  ));
  return (
    <div>
      {teams.role}
      {teams.winrate}
      {pokemap}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Teams;
```

I get the error that the nested team.map is not a function, because after the first map, the nested map is just an array containing an object instead of multiple arrays but I have no idea how to get around it.

EDIT: FIXED :)
Here's the new component:

```
const Teams = ({ teams }) => {
  console.log(teams);
  let pokemap = teams.slice(1).map((team, index) => (
    <React.Fragment key={index}>
      <br />{" "}
      <div class="container">
        <div class="bout">{team[0].bout}</div>{" "}
        <div>
          Score:
          <br />
          {team[0].wins && team[0].wins + "-"}
          {team[0].wins && 3 - team[0].wins}
        </div>
        <br />
        {Array.isArray(team) &&
          team.slice(1).map((pokemon) => (
            <React.Fragment key={pokemon.pokemon}>
              <div class="child">
                <img src={pokemon.sprite} />
                <p>{pokemon.pokemon}</p>
              </div>
            </React.Fragment>
          ))}
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  ));
  return (
    <div>
      Win Rate: {teams[0].winrate}%{pokemap}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: try adding a console.log(teams); before  let pokemap = teams.map((team, index) ..., this way you can visualize the structure of your teams array. and if the mapping is KO then you know where to start ( Also You are using const team = []; so teams will be [[],..] and not [{},..] )

Comment: I guess the `map()` that stops working is the nested one: `team.map((pokemon) => ...)`. That's because `teams` will be an array of objects, not an array of arrays and consequently  `team` will be an object not an array.

Comment: Add the console.log(teams)  first so you can be sure of this array's structure :)

Comment: added console.log(teams) - also changed the `const` to `let` on the arrays.. will update main post.

Comment: @lbsn is correct, but my head hurts and I have no idea how to fix it lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your data contains both objects and arrays you need to check within the first iteration level if the current item is an array and only call `map()` in that case:

```
{Array.isArray(team) && team.map((pokemon) => (
  <React.Fragment key={pokemon.pokemon}>
    <br /> <div class="bout">{pokemon.bout}</div>
    <div class="child">
      <img src={pokemon.sprite} />
      <p>{pokemon.pokemon}</p>
    </div>
  </React.Fragment>
))}
```

Comment: Amazing, I used this combined with `teams.slice(1).map((team, index) => (`
... since the first part of the data isn't formatted the same.